# Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire()

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using Drupal Version 6.25.

I duplicated an existing drupal page and tried to install it locally on my system.
After the Step where I entered the database information I got this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire()

it seems to be located in:

> modules/system/system.module on line 810

but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Hopefully somebody of you know how to fix it because I can't go any further and I need this duplication locally.

Comment: Do you have a lock.inc file in the /includes/ folder of your local copy?

Comment: What do you mean by "I duplicated an existing drupal page and tried to install it locally on my system."?

Comment: @scronide - Yes I have a *lock.inc* in the */includes/* folder.

Comment: @VladStratulat - I followed this step by step instruction to duplicate the existing page.
[ostraining.com](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-migrate/)

Comment: So basically you want to replicate a website on your local machine, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the PHP in `system.module` add:

```
include_once './includes/lock.inc';
```

Then run `update.php` and clear your cache.

Comment: and @VladStratulat. 
I wanted to use Drupal with phoneGap and tried to install it locally into my project. But unfortunately you can't run .php files and there is another better way to combine Drupal and mobile via the "Services" module. Now I try my best with that. Thanks for you help anyway.