# drush fails to clear cache: Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire()

Tags: caching, drupal, drush, drupal-5

I have installed Drush 5.6 on my ubuntu machine, and I am now working on a Drupal theme, so I need to clear the cache frequently, but I cannot seem to do it with drush...

When I run the `drush cc all` inside my drupal site folder, I get the message that it successfully cleared the drush cache.

When I instead run `drush cc` inside my drupal site folder I get only 3 options (even though I have seen other people get more options here...): to cancel, to clear drush cache, or to clear registry cache. Here I tried to clear the registry cache and got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire()
```

pointing me to some bootstrap.inc file

I will be very happy if someone could help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564017/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-lock-acquire-duplicating-drupal-site

Comment: I tried the suggestion in that thread but instead got this error now: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_insert() in /var/www/mysite/includes/lock.inc on line 128` so not so much better... I am still wondering why I get only 3 options when running `drush cc`, some get the option to clear css+js etc? It seems somehow that drush has no access to these caches.. anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The reason is `drush` was not able to use the `php` with MAMP. So you need to add path to your MAMP's `php` location to `~/.bash_profile`.

For me its something like:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin:$PATH
```

I am using PHP 5.3 in MAMP, check what version you are using and write the absolute path then do source `~/.bash_profile`.

Restart MAMP and re-check.